# efficient way of adding up subarrays to create a big array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-efficient

Let `N` be bigger than `k`, `M` be the `N` by `N` array with 0 entries and `L` be a list of lists of `k` by `k` arrays (edit: `L` is essentially a matrix where each entry is a matrix). I want to iterate through the pairs (i, j) with  1 <= i,j <= N and add up a `k` by `k` matrix to `M[i:i+k, j:j+k]`, as in the following Python code:

```
for i in range(N - k + 1):
    for j in range(N - k + 1):
        M[i:i+k, j:j+k] += L[i][j]
```

What would be a Pythonic & computationally efficient way of implementing this?

Edit: example N=3, k=2,

```
L[0,0] = [1,2]
         [3,4]    

L[0,1] = [5,6]
         [7,8]

L[1,0] = [9,10]
         [11,12]      

L[1,1] =[13,14]    
        [15,16].
```

initially, M is

```
    [ 0, 0, 0]
    [ 0, 0, 0]
    [ 0, 0, 0]
```

at i=j=0, M becomes

```
[ 1, 2, 0]   
[ 3, 4, 0]    
[ 0, 0, 0]
```

at i=0, j=1, M becomes

```
      [0,5,6] 
 M+ = [0,7,8]
      [0,0,0]
```

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't support Latex

Comment: You are also skipping the last blocks of your matrix. Shouldn't it be `range(N - k + 1)` instead?

Comment: @mathfux since array indexation starts at 0 in Python, i think i'm not skipping any blocks?

Comment: I think you do because, the highest `i` and `j` are `N-k-1` and `i:i+k` stops at `i+k-1` which is `(N-k-1) + k -1` = `N - 2`. You need `N - 1`

Comment: Add an example array for each of the variables to test.

Comment: As long as `L` is a list of lists, each (k,k) matrix has to be indexed individually with `[i][j]`, so you have to do that kind of iteration.  If `L` is a (N-k,N-k,k,k) array, it may be possible to work out a mapping/indexing that allows you to add larger blocks.  I'd have to setup a small example case to work out the details.

Comment: @mathfux you are right, edited.

Comment: @Hector Haffenden added an example.

Comment: @hpaulj  algorithmically this must be approx N^2 k^2, but i was thinking there some way of accessing the arrays in python which would significantly speed up things as compared to numpy?

Comment: In your example, the matrix M+, are the positions row=0, col=0 and col=0,row=1 meant to be 0 - I assumed it was iterative from the begining of the question

Comment: Shouldn't it become `[[1, 7, 6], [3, 11, 8], [0, 0, 0]]` at `i=0,j=1` since (2, 4) overlaps with (5, 7)?

Answer (score 1):

So with your example:

```
In [30]: N, k = 3,2
In [31]: nk = N-k+1
In [32]: L = np.arange(1,(nk*nk*k*k)+1).reshape(nk,nk,k,k)
In [40]: M = np.zeros((N,N),int)
    ...: for i in range(nk):
    ...:     for j in range(nk):
    ...:         M[i:i+k, j:j+k] += L[i,j]
    ...: 
In [41]: M
Out[41]: 
array([[ 1,  7,  6],
       [12, 34, 22],
       [11, 27, 16]])
```

I can recreate this with sliding windows:

```
In [74]: M1 = np.zeros((N,N),int)
In [75]: M2 = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(M1,(2,2), writeable=True
    ...: )
In [76]: for i in range(nk):
    ...:     for j in range(nk):
    ...:         M2[i, j] += L[i,j]
    ...: 
In [77]: M2
Out[77]: 
array([[[[ 1,  7],
         [12, 34]],

        [[ 7,  6],
         [34, 22]]],


       [[[12, 34],
         [11, 27]],

        [[34, 22],
         [27, 16]]]])
In [78]: M1
Out[78]: 
array([[ 1,  7,  6],
       [12, 34, 22],
       [11, 27, 16]])
```

This has the same sort of iteration.  The next step would be to use `np.add.at` to perform the iterative addition.

```
< more work to come >
```

I can't do the "obvious" += addition because of the buffering that `add.at` explains:

```
In [79]: M1 = np.zeros((N,N),int)
In [80]: M2 = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(M1,(2,2), writeable=True
    ...: )
In [81]: M2 += L
In [82]: M1
Out[82]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  6],
       [ 9, 13, 14],
       [11, 15, 16]])
```

With `@mathfux` suggestion:

```
In [83]: x, y, z, t = np.indices(L.shape)
In [84]: M1 = np.zeros((N,N),int)
In [85]: M2 = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(M1,(2,2), writeable=True
    ...: )
In [86]: np.add.at(M2, (x,y,z,t), L)
In [87]: M1
Out[87]: 
array([[ 1,  7,  6],
       [12, 34, 22],
       [11, 27, 16]])
```

Or without explicitly naming the 4 indices arrays (doesn't really matter since `L` will always be 4d, regardless of `N` and `k`).

```
In [100]: np.add.at(M2, tuple(np.indices(L.shape)), L)
In [101]: M1
Out[101]: 
array([[ 1,  7,  6],
       [12, 34, 22],
       [11, 27, 16]])
```

The `add.at` docs mention slices, so may be possible to use it with `M` directly, rather than via the sliding_windows.

Comment: I think OP want to work with any L which is a list of lists of k by k arrays. Personally for me, it was not clear whats the shape of L until he gave some examples. I think your example is rather minimal than general.

Comment: @mathfux, so far I'm just fleshing out the OPs example, as step toward visualizing the problem.  I "vectorize" by getting a mental, almost visual, image of the action, and then "thinking outside" of the iterative box.

Comment: Yes, I agree this is essential part of a process. Hope this is what OP wants

Comment: This is a right way to go. You could use `x, y, z, t = np.indices(L.shape)` and `np.add.at(M2, (x,y,z,t), L)` instead of `M2 += L` to finish your solution.

Comment: @mathfux, yes that what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass `N` and `k` explicitly because a shape of resulting array is well defined once you know `L`. I'll just refactor @hpaulj solution in order to get rid of these excessive values:

```
def kernel_array_sum(kernel_array, dtype=int):
    N, k = np.array(kernel_array.shape[:2]), np.array(kernel_array.shape[2:])
    M = np.zeros(N + k - 1, dtype=dtype)
    A = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(M, k)
    x, y, z, t = np.indices(A.shape)
    np.add.at(A, (x,y,z,t), kernel_array)
    return M

L = np.array([[[[ 1, 2], [ 3, 4]], [[ 5, 6], [ 7, 8]]], 
              [[[ 9,10], [11,12]], [[13,14], [15,16]]],
              [[[17,18], [19,20]], [[21,22], [23,24]]]])

>>> kernel_array_sum(L)
array([[ 1,  7,  6],
       [12, 34, 22],
       [28, 66, 38],
       [19, 43, 24]])
```

Now this was rather educational. If you want to it in a more performant way `numba` is a better option:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def _nkas(M, L):
    for i in range(L.shape[0]):
        for j in range(L.shape[1]):
            M[i:i+k[0], j:j+k[1]] += L[i][j]
            
def numba_kernel_array_sum(kernel_array):
    N, k = np.array(kernel_array.shape[:2]), np.array(kernel_array.shape[2:])
    M = np.zeros(N + k - 1, dtype=int)
    _nkas(M, kernel_array)
    return 
>>> numba_kernel_array_sum(L)
array([[ 1,  7,  6],
       [12, 34, 22],
       [28, 66, 38],
       [19, 43, 24]])
```

Note that `parallel=True` option is not available since items of `M` are reassigned multiple times which is not possible in parallel. Although it's still faster near 4x times on my computer than `numpy` solution.